# Kubernetes containerized .NET 5.0 API fails to connect to SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2012 R2 because of cipher suites issue

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, tls1.2

I have a .NET 5.0 API running in Kubernetes.

When the API attempts to connect to a SQL Server database, schannel on the DB server logs this error:

> An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client
> application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client
> application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request
> has failed.

The same API running in k8s can connect to other SQL Server DBs just fine.  Also, if I run the API locally in Visual Studio, it can connect to the DB fine.

How do I resolve this?  I got a list of the cipher suites the DB server is using by looking at SSL Configuration Settings in Local Group Policy Editor.  How do I see what the API is using for cipher suites?

Comment: Are you building your containers from a public image (e.g.: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`)? You should be able to open a console to a running container and execute `/usr/bin/openssl ciphers -v` to view the available ciphers.

Comment: Yes @AlwaysLearning I am building from the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 public image.  I am able to view the ciphers with the command you provided.  I noticed that all the cipher suites from the Windows Server 2012 are prefixed with "TLS_", but NONE are prefixed that way in the ciphers list generated from the container console.